# Azure IoT Hub different behavior for different Devices on D2C send operations

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I'm currently investigating a very strange situation with Azure IoT Hub.

I'm sending a small payload (1 JSON Document ~ 100 Bytes) using MQTT and the C# SDK.

When i send the payload using DeviceId "test1" (which is a valid, enabled device in IoT Hub), every call to SendEventsAsync takes more than 10 seconds to complete.
After a short period of time, the send operations fail totally with exceptions like this:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common.Exceptions.ServerErrorException: {"Message":"ErrorCode:ServerError;InternalServerError","ExceptionMessage":"Tracking ID:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-TimeStamp:01/29/2018 10:50:36"}
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions.UnauthorizedException: CONNECT failed: RefusedServerUnavailable
DotNetty.Transport.Channels.ClosedChannelException: E/A-Fehler
```

When i send the same payload from the same client machine to the same IoT Hub using a different device id ("test2"), everything is fine and a send operation takes < 1 second.

I tried deleting the device in the device registry and re-creating it but this didn't change the behavior.

Can anybody tell me what could cause this behavior and how to fix it?

Best regards
Markus

Comment: Can you test it with MQTTBox Client http://workswithweb.com/mqttbox.html

Comment: Before the send operation fails can you see the sent messages in the device explorer?

Comment: I'm kind of sorry to say that the problem went away which is quite scary as i don't want to run into those situations when this solution goes live. So, @RitaHan-MSFT and Roman Kiss - i couldn't test your suggestions.